# How do real distinctions in God lead to act and potency composition?

Tags: thomas-aquinas, metaphysics, divine-simplicity

Thomists believe that there is no real distinction between perfections of God as God is pure act. My understanding is that they reject real distinctions between perfections because that leads to act and potency composition, but why would that be the case?

Comment: I'm studying simplicity and related topics myself, though I haven't come across the term "act and potency composition" before. This may be relevant: https://catholiclibrary.org/library/view?docId=/Contemporary-EN/XCT.142.html&chunk.id=00000015

Comment: This might be better on the [philosophy.se] site - would you like me to migrate it?

Comment: @curiousdannii I did ask there..but I felt it was more suited for christians and those who are more familiar with divine simplicity.

Comment: This is metaphysical and philosophical. I have voted to close the question as unsuitable for this site.

Comment: @MichalRyszardWojcik wow thanks..God bless you.

Comment: @Vihan I don't want to encourage anyone to use ChatGPT other than for amusement. It does not know anything, and confidently makes up nonsense.

Comment: This can be studied interactively like this https://hf.co/chat/r/w6zO9SF by asking a Thomas Aquinas Emulator.